# How to merge two animated gif with javascript?

Tags: javascript, gif

I have a web application that allows users to upload animated gifs. The gifs are displayed on the same page using `<img>` tags and the user can move them around in the page. When the user finishes to move the gifs i need to export the result into one gif that includes them all.

For example, the user may upload two animated gifs files and places them side by side on the web page, I need to export them in one gif file that display the two gifs side by side.

I was thinking to extract all the frames from every uploaded gif, combine the frames from every gif into one frame (like result_frame_1 = gif1_frame_1 + gif2_frame1, result_frame_2 = gif1_frame_2 + gif2_frame2, etc) and rearrange the resulting frames to get the new gif.

I need to do this with javascript, are there libs that could help me with this task? Basically I would need a library to extract the frames from a gif, manipulate them and recreate a gif from them.

Comment: So far as I know, you cannot do this with javascript.  The image display that you are relying upon is embodied within the web browser software and it is not exposed to you.

Comment: You could put the images onto a canvas once they're in an Element together, using `canvasContext.drawImage`. Then you can send `const blob = canvas.toBlob()` in a `FormDataInstance.append('fileName.png', blob)` via `XMLHttpRequest`, then write the file on your Server, but I would just send the image urls to the Server *(via XMLHttpRequest)*, where you get and merge them together on the Server.

Answer (score 0):

There are no libraries currently for this. But you can use ffmpg wasm to extract frames from a GIF or any other frame extractors. Pass these frames to canvas imagedraw looping over both GIF frames one by one. (draw 1st GIF 1st frame then 2nd GIF 1st frame so on for all frames) With all the result frames combine new frames to form a GIF by ffmpg.